# They swindled hundreds of dollars out of him. vs. swindled him out of hundreds of dollars

Tags: sentence-usage, verb-usage

> They swindled hundreds of dollars out of him.

vs.

> They swindled him out of hundreds of dollars.

The question is 'swindle sb out of sth' vs. 'swindle sth out of sb'

Why the two sentences above make the same meaning even the structure is totally different?

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22swindled+it+out+of+me%22) are lots of written instances of the sequence *swindled **it** out of **me***. And [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22swindled+me+out+of+it%22) are loads more with the sequence *swindled **me** out of **it***. Both versions are semantically equivalent, obviously. I know there's a word for this feature of English, but I can't come up with it myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's the meaning of 'out of' here?

Comment: Same as usual, I guess *(**out = away = gone**)*. Compare more obscure idiomatic usages like *If I sell it for that price, I'll be **out of pocket***, or *When he cashed up the till he found he was **out £10***

Comment: I think you have to use some common sense.  It doesn't really make sense to think "They stole him from hundreds of dollars by trickery", like he belonged to the hundreds of dollars, and the thieves stole him.

Comment: But we should also note that **swindled X out of him** is a very uncommon way of phrasing it.  ["Swindled **him** out of **X**" is immensely more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=swindled+*+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @stangdon What's the meaning of 'out of' in your "swindled him out of X"?

Comment: @BEBYGONES "out of" X means that he was *lacking* X.